# Adding an integer value into string in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hello Every one,
                I have an issue that is, I want to add an integer into a string for example I have two text field one is called series start and the other one is called series end now if user enters

> FAHD1000001 into series start field

AND

> FAHD1000100 into series end field

the algorithm should store 100 values into the database with increment into the each entry that is going to store into the database. i.e

> FAHD1000001, FAHD1000002, FAHD1000003, ........., FAHD1000100

Is it possible to do so, if yes then how. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do something like this but there is a loop hole if you have any numeric value in name like F1AHD00001 than it will not work

```
$str1 = $request['start'];
$str2 = $request['end'];
$startint=preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$str1);
$endint=preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$str2 );
$words = preg_replace('/[[:digit:]]/', '', $str1);
for($i=$startint;$i<$endint;$i++){
    $newstring=$words.$i;
    //Save this new String
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much you have almost solved my problem now i will make my own regex which will handle that loop hole

Comment: Extremely sorry bro completely forgot to accept the answer due to the excitement